# Unregister tasks created with system user

Tags: powershell

I have a script that attempts to create a task that will run whether the user is logged on or not, overwriting any previous versions of the task if necessary. After some searching it seems that powershell needs to create the task under the system user to create a task in this way, like so:

```bsh
$P = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
$D = New-ScheduledTask -Action $A -Principal $P -Trigger $triggersList -Settings $S -Description $Desc; 
Register-ScheduledTask Test -InputObject $D | Out-Null
```

This code works fine and is creating the task how I want it when checking it from task scheduler. However, Powershell appears to only lists tasks created under the current user, and is unable to see or unregister tasks created by system. Previous versions of the task may exist and need to be removed/updated, how would I go about unregistering it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following script will help you:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Find-scheduled-tasks-c397716a
I tried to reproduce the problem and created the task under another user (as Systemaccount), but can get it with Powershell `Get-ScheduledTask`...maybe this is version dependent. I tested this with the following version:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.592
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.592
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

## Edit:

I can see the task running powershell as Admin (elevated rights). With a "Normal" Powershell Instance i can't see this task.

Comment: It seems that I may have misidentified my error, as I now notice that when I run powershell as admin the `Get-ScheduledTask` command returns the error:
`Get-ScheduledTask : The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ScheduledTask
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...T_ScheduledTask) [Get-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070002,Get-ScheduledTask`